# Could any optimizations be made to this code to make it run faster?

Tags: python

I have completed my attempt at a code challenge, in which I have to figure out the longest possible prefix between a list of words. I think (hope) my solution is okay, but it isn't efficient enough, and so won't run, could anyone suggest optimizations to my code? Thank you so much for any help, and please ignore any silly mistakes - I'm still learning :(.
words were ["flower","flow","flight"] and ["dog","racecar","car"]

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        if len(strs) == 0:
            return("")
        if len(strs) == 1:
            return(strs[0])
        
        prefix = strs[0]
        wordLength = len(strs)
        
        for i in range(wordLength):
            
            while prefix != strs[i+1]:
                prefix = prefix[:-1]
                
            if len(prefix) == 0:
                return("")
        return(prefix)
```

Comment: Please clarify by showing the expected outputs for these two lists

Comment: This code looks buggy.  For instance, in the `for` loop `i` ranges from `0` to `len(strs)-1`.  So on the last iteration, `i+1` is `len(strs)`, so `strs[i+1]` is an out-of-bounds reference.  You probably want change `strs[i+1]` to `strs[i]`, and change the `for` loop to `for i in range(1, wordLength)`.

Comment: But that still doesn't seem right.  It fixes the indexing bug, but the `while` loop isn't doing a prefix comparison.  It's reducing `prefix` and it matches the *entire* string, rather than the start of it.  You probably want `strs[i].startswith(prefix)`.

Comment: On a stylistic note, it's unusual to use `return(val)` in Python.  Just use `return val`.  The parentheses serve no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your runtime by using generators and builtin python functions (as these are executed in C):

```
def longest_common_prefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
    if len(strs) == 0:
        return ""
    
    prefix = strs[0]
    while prefix: # aka while prefix not empty
        if all(s.startswith(prefix) for s in strs):
            return prefix
        prefix = prefix[:-1]
    assert False, "this line should never be reached"
```

You can also generally improve your complexity by not double checking characters you already know are equal:

```
def longest_common_prefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
    if len(strs) == 0:
        return ""
    shortest_str_len = min(len(s) for s in strs)
    for i in range(0, shortest_str_len):
        current_char = strs[0][i]
        if not all(s[i] == current_char for s in strs):
            return strs[0][:i]
    assert False, "this line should never be reached"
```

The second approach removes is `O(len(strs)*len(shortest_str)` instead of `O(len(strs)*len(shorest_str)^2)`

Comment: You can't *return s* as it's not in scope

Comment: My fault - I meant prefex...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this solution is particularly readable (which is bad) but it's food for thought

```
from itertools import takewhile

def longest_common_prefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
    return ''.join(y[0] for y in takewhile(lambda x: all(map(x[0].__eq__, x[1:])), zip(*strs)))
```

Comment: looks like code golf haha